# How do microbes develop resistance to anitmicrobial peptides?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, bacteriology, immune-system

I would like to better understand how bacteria use the "strategy" of alternations to lipid A and membrane proteins in order to resist antimicrobial peptides of the immune system?

It is my understanding that the by altering its lipid A, the bacterium makes its membrane less hydrophobic, increasing hydrophilicity, resulting in an increased amount of fluidity for the outer membrane.

This should then inhibit the hydrophobic portion of antimicrobial peptide embedding into the lipid membrane of bacteria.

Is this accurate? Is there anything I am missing about these alterations than confer resistance?